# Class internal thread-safety

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am writing a class in Java which is internally multithreaded, in that it initializes and uses a separate thread to update its private fields.

```java
class Foo {
    private volatile Byte channel = new Byte(0);
    private volatile Byte mode = new Byte(0);

    public Foo() {
        Thread t = new Thread(new UpdateFields());
        t.setDaemon(true);
        t.start();
    }

    public Byte getChannel() {
        return this.channel;
    }  

    public Byte getMode() {
        return this.mode;
    }

    private class UpdateFields implements Runnable {
        @Override public void run() {
            Byte data[];
            //get new data[]...
            channel = data[0];
            mode = data[1];
        }
    } 
}
```

My question is, is this class internally thread-safe? From what I have read regarding immutable objects such as Byte etc. are that they are inherently thread-safe.

EDIT: added default values to fields

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> My question is, is this class internally thread-safe? From what I have read regarding immutable objects such as Byte etc. are that they are inherently thread-safe.

The thread-safety problem that I see with your class is that you are updating two fields that look to be related.  It could be possible, because of race conditions, to see a new `channel` value and an old `mode` value.  I would use a `volatile ChannelMode` object instead of your two `volatile` fields.

```
public class ChannelMode {
    private byte channel;
    private byte mode;
    public byte getChannel() {
       return channel;
    }
    public byte getMode() {
       return mode;
    }
}
```

Although not necessary, I like to use the `Atomic*` classes instead of `volatile` directly so I'd use an `AtomicReference<ChannelMode>`.  So your code would look like:

```
private AtomicReference<ChannelMode> channelModeRef =
    new AtomicReference<ChannelMode>(
        new ChannelMode(INITIAL_CHANNEL, INITIAL_MODE));
...
Byte data[];
// get new data[]...
// atomic operation to set the new channel-mode
channelModeRef.set(new ChannelMode(data[0], data[1]);
```

If your inner thread updates the `ChannelMode` every so often then your class should be thread safe in that the values will be atomically updated and memory properly synchronized.

Comment: so to maintain thread-safety of the class fields I should use AtomicReference<V> class such that when the fields are read or written to, it is synchronized

Comment: Well the `volatile` ensures memory synchronization.  What the `AtomicReference` (which uses a `volatile` reference internally) does is ensure _atomic_ updating of the two fields @GeoP.

Comment: @Gray The atomic reference is of little value here. Your real change is to encapsulate channel and mode in a separate immutable object. The reference to `ChannelMode` is always going to point to either the new or the old version. Calls to `getChannel()` and `getMode()` could still straddle the change. You of course could add a `getChannelMode()` method, but the `AtomicReference` buys you nothing.

Comment: This is true @pamphlet but I always like to use the Atomic* classes instead of using `volatile` directly.  But I'll update my answer to say that.

Comment: @Gray If on the other hand I had multiple unreleated fields, I should use `AtomicReference` with each one to main thread-safety, am I right?

Comment: You could @GeoP although as pamphlet points out, they aren't necessary.  `volatile` ensures proper memory synchronization.

Answer (score 1):

If you change the inner fields the class is not immutable. An immutable class doesn't change. This means that your class is not thread-safe.

That's true that if you do not expose any setters or any other method that changes your class it's supposed to immutable, but in this case you change it internally. The **inherently thread-safe** means that it cannot be changes so there you don't need to fear different threads would race and corrupt each other's data. This is certainly not the case here.

Comment: Just because a class is not immutable doesn't mean that it is not thread safe.  There are also thread safety issues that can come up even if a class _is_ immutable -- for example constructor visibility issues.

Comment: The real question is does the inner thread update the outer thread's values in a thread-safe way.

Comment: @Gray- I answered OP's question. (S)he asked if it's thread safe because it's immutable. Also, in this case, it is not thread anyway.

Comment: The OP is ultimately asking about thread-safety -- they do mention immutability but that's not the core question here.

Answer (score 1):

Your class is not threadsafe.
Reason: If `//get new data[]...` is a time consuming step then other methods may try to read inner fields before they are initialized by your inner thread. An inner thread in constructor will not stop the object construction and initialization, so until the data is prepared it may have inconsistent state.